# Something weird while converting IPV6 to IPV4 Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, ip

First, I get my Ip address with the help of @Ip as follows:

```
public async getUserIp(@Ip() ip) {
    // Now my Ip is => ::ffff:10.244.199.11

    // Here , I convert IP6 to IP4.
    const result = this.cleanupAddress(ip) //  10.244.199.11
}

public cleanupAddress(str: any) {
    // if it's a valid ipv6 address, and if its a mapped ipv4 address,
    // then clean it up. otherwise return the original string.
    if (ipaddr.IPv6.isValid(str)) {
        var addr = ipaddr.IPv6.parse(str);
        if (addr.isIPv4MappedAddress())
            return addr.toIPv4Address().toString();
    }
    return str
}
```

Result of converting (**v6 to v4**) is `10.244.199.11` . When I google **what is my IP address**, it shows `151.233.251.87`

NOTE:

With the help of [this site](https://www.whatsmydns.net/ipv6-to-ipv4), I convert IPV6 to IPV4 online, the result is `10.244.199.11`.

**I test them in production. Why did I get two different results?**

Comment: Are you behind a load balancer in production?